# Adding new look and feel changes to the package for second attempt of security review affect the process?

Tags: appexchange, security-review

We got the result for App Exchange security review as "**Your App did not pass**" with few issues. We have rectified those issue and also done few look and feel (added slds) changes to the Visualforce page. No new logic or functionality added to the app.

We are planning to submit the app for second attempt of security review.

Will the security review team accept the new look and feel changes? Please suggest. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The security team is not concerned about the user interface (UI) or the user experience (UX). They are concerned about all manners of security-related issues, like injection attacks, cross-site scripting attacks, data leakage, and so on. As long as your code doesn't raise any red flags in that department, you should be okay.